# How can i Watir scrape the values from this table into instance variables in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, watir

This is the table I have:

```
<tbody><tr>
                  <td class="rhs">Number:</td>
                  <td id="number"><strong>2</strong></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
                  <td class="rhs">Total:</td>
                  <td id="total"><strong>£60,000</strong></td>           
       </tr>
       <tr>
                  <td class="rhs">GrandTotal</td>
                  <td><strong>£200,000</strong></td>           
       </tr>
       <tr>
                  <td class="rhs">Limit:</td>
                  <td><strong>£550,000</strong></td>         
       </tr>
       <tr>
                  <td class="rhs">Frequency:</td>
                  <td><strong>Annually</strong></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
                       <td class="rhs">Percentage:</td>
                       <td><strong>0%</strong></td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="display-total">
                      <td class="rhs">Year 1:</td>
                      <td><strong>£480.00</strong></td>
       </tr>        
</tbody></table>
```

And I am trying with Watir to 'scrape' the values and store them in variables in my application.

```
def scrape_quote
        puts @quote.number = @browser.td(:id, 'number').text
        @quote.total = @browser.td(:id, 'total').text
        @quote.grand_total= @browser.tr(:index => '3').td(:index => '1').text
        @quote.limit = @browser.tr(:index => '4').td(:index => '1').text
        @quote.frequency = @browser.tr(:index => '5').td(:index => '1').text
        @quote.percentage = @browser.tr(:index => '6').td(:index => '1').text
        @quote.yr1 = @browser.tr(:index => '7').td(:index => '1').text

        puts @quote.number + ' ' +  @quote.total  + ' ' +  @quote.grand_total
         + ' ' + @quote.limit + ' ' +  @quote.frequency + ' ' +  @quote.commission
          + ' ' +  @quote.yr1
end
```

(Just puts'd to see whether the method had worked or not, once working I'll actually save them in the model.)

Unfortunately the above isn't capturing and or storing those values as intended. Can you help me see the error of my ways please.

Thankyou.

Comment: It would help you if you clarify exactly what the output is. At a minimum, the `:index` for the `tr` elements looks to be off by one. You should also verify the outputs before you store them in `@quote` - ie is the problem with the interaction with Watir or the interaction with `@quote`.

Answer (score 0):

You try to access the values using String for index value, which should be an integer. In any case, the final code should look like this:

```
 rows = @b.trs #Retrieve all trs
scraped_values = {} #Creating a dictionary to store scraped values

for row in rows #iterate over trs
  scraped_values[row[1].id] = row[1].text #retrieve the data
end
puts scraped_values
```

Answer (score 0):

In watir, putting s after an element tag gets all the elements with that tag and putting it on an array.

So in your case if you put the command `@browser.trs.length` the value would be 7, since you have 7 rows in your table.

As for the id, I always use `@browser.td(:id=>'id')` and it always works, though `@browser.td(:id, 'id')`  works for me too.

```
def scrape_quote
        puts @quote.number = @browser.td(:id=>'number').text
        @quote.total = @browser.td(:id=>'total').text
        @quote.grand_total= @browser.trs[3].tds[1].text
        @quote.limit = @browser.trs[4].tds[1].text
        @quote.frequency = @browser.trs[5].tds[1].text
        @quote.percentage = @browser.trs[6].tds[1].text
        @quote.yr1 = @browser.trs[7].tds[1].text

        puts @quote.number + ' ' +  @quote.total  + ' ' +  @quote.grand_total
         + ' ' + @quote.limit + ' ' +  @quote.frequency + ' ' +  @quote.commission
          + ' ' +  @quote.yr1
end
```